# How to group peak points corresponding to the same hill in signal plot

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have a list of points where I need to find peak points and group them. I am using `find_peak()` function from [scipy.signal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html#scipy.signal.find_peaks) to find the peak points, Now I need to group the peak points which correspond to the same hill (as mentioned below). How can we do this, any suggestion would be of great help.

**Sample images**
[image]
[image]

**Code**

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

# lst has list of points
A = np.array(lst)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(A)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(lst)
plt.plot(peaks, A[peaks], "ro")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical way to group peaks is to low-pass filter the waveform.  Lower the frequency cut-off of the low-pass filter until the peaks you think belong together for your "hills" merge.  Then try the find peaks function.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a typical distance between two "real" peaks, you can add a supposed minimum distance between peaks as an argument. Peaks that are closer to each other than this distance will be neglected.

`peaks, _ = find_peaks(A, distance=40)`